# jQuery Tab is caching TabID

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-tabs

I defined my jQuery tabs like this:

```
 $('#serviceTabs').tabs({
    idPrefix: 'ui-subtabs-',
    spinner: 'Retrieving data...',
    cache: false,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if(checkServiceTabs(ui.index))
        {
            $('#ui-subtabs-'+(currentDetailTab+1)).html(" ");
            currentDetailTab = ui.index;
            return true;
     }
        else
            return false;
    },
    collapsible: true
});
```

Unfortunately after reloading my page the index of my tabs is raised incrementally.
So on first request my TabID's look like:

```
#ui-subtabs-1, #ui-subtabs-2, #ui-subtabs-3
```

after reloading my page it looks like:

```
#ui-subtabs-4, #ui-subtabs-5, #ui-subtabs-6
```

The side effect is, that the tabs are locked after reload. The select event doesn't work anymore.

FYI: The tabs are in a DIV and merged with `$.get` function. 
So i don't reload the whole page but only the div.

Before the new request I already blank the div with `.html(" ")` and I also tried

```
$('#serviceTabs').tabs("destroy");
```

Does anybody have an idea how to delete the TabID cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `tabIndex` variable from which the TabID is coming from is encapsulated in the anonymous function of the Tabs plugin, making it totally invisible to the *outside world*. It is only incremented and the plugin offers no method to be able to reset it. Even destroying the instance of the plugin would not help.

On the [overview](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) page of the plugin's documentation though, it is specified that the tab containers can be references using the Title attribute of the `<a>` elements serving as tab buttons.

You would have then this kind of markup for the tab buttons:

```
<li><a href="hello/world.html" title="My Tab 1"> ... </a></li>
```

This will create tab containers with the title as ID (replacing spaces with underscores):

```
<div id="My_Tab_1"> ... </div>
```

You would have then to modify you select method accordingly.